# How to get the version number from a given XSLT file .

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-3.0

Say I have an XSLT file like below:

```
    `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-
       prefixes="xs math"
       version="3.0">`

....... and so on.
```

I need the output as 3.0 because the above file has version="3.0". I want to use C# to get this given the XSLT is in string format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XElement.Parse(yourString).Attribute("version").Value`, where you add `using System.Xml.Linq;`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview for details of the used API.

Comment: What if input is a Stream and not string?

Comment: Well, if you want to use that API like any other API then start reading its documentation, the class `XElement` has a `Load` method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.load?view=netframework-4.7.1 that has one overload taking a `Stream` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string version = (string)doc.Root.Attribute("version");
        }
    }
}
```